# How to remove <br/> tag from Textarea?

Tags: html, django, tags

I'm using Django to construct a simple personal website. I just built a basic email form. Here's the models.py file for it:

```
from django.db import models

class Message(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is the corresponding forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from rksite.models import Message

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200,help_text="Name:")
    email = forms.EmailField(help_text="Email:")
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Subject:")
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.Textarea, help_text="Message:")

    class Meta:
        model = Message #link the model to the form
```

And finally, I'll also include the form's html page below:

```
{% extends 'rksite/base.html' %}

{% block title %}RaghavKumarContact{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contact Me</h1>
<br />
<form class="span6" id="email_form" method="POST" action="/home/contact/">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, no matter what I do, the "br/" tag shows up inside the "Message" Textarea field. Here's what I see on my webpage:

[image]

How can I get rid of this tag from this Textarea?

EDIT:
This is what it'll look like if I don't have the `linebreaks`filter applied:

[image]

What is an alternative to the linebreaks filter??

Comment: You can try the removetags template filter: ``{{ field|removetags:"br"|safe }}`` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: That doesn't work. I need linebreaks below some of these fields otherwise everything prints out on just one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `linebreaks` here:

`{{ field|linebreaks }}`

That renders the widget for the form, then passes the entire rendered HTML block through the `linebreaks` filter. That filter converts newlines into `<br />` tags, and the rendering for a `Textarea` widget includes a newline before the text:

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    if value is None:
        value = ''
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
    return format_html('<textarea{}>\r\n{}</textarea>',
                       flatatt(final_attrs),
                       force_text(value))
```

(Source from https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L435)

I'm not sure why you'd want to pass the field values though `linebreaks` - an HTML textarea should handle regular linebreaks in the message text just fine, if that's what you're worrying about.

Comment: If I don't use linebreaks, the whole form is rendered on one line and looks ugly as hell. I'll send you a snapshot of how it will look.

Comment: Got it to work my removing linebreaks and instead adding a "br" tag after each field in that for loop. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you're going field by field you need some kind of divider - I usually wrapped each field in a <p> elements.